# How to read a XPS file in C# using Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, windows, xps

I am duplicating my Windows Application to Web Application. In between i got some problem with  XPS file. In Windows Application i am reading the XPS file with the following code..,

```
  List<string> lData = new List<string>();
        using (XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(FullfileName, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            FixedDocumentSequence docSeq = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
            Dictionary<string, string> docPageText = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for (int pageNum = 0; pageNum < docSeq.DocumentPaginator.PageCount; pageNum++)
            {
                DocumentPage docPage = docSeq.DocumentPaginator.GetPage(pageNum);
                foreach (System.Windows.UIElement uie in ((FixedPage)docPage.Visual).Children)
                {
                    if (uie is System.Windows.Documents.Glyphs)
                    {
                        lData.Add(((System.Windows.Documents.Glyphs)uie).UnicodeString);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now if i copy the same thing in Web means i am getting an error.

```
'The invocation of the constructor on type 'System.Windows.Documents.DocumentReference'
 that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.
' Line number '3' and line position '20'.
```

this error is occurred in the following line of my Code

```
FixedDocumentSequence docseq=xpsDoc.GetFixedDoCumentSequence()
```

Please help me regarding this

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that the application runs in full trust

  > [Quote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.xpsdocument.getfixeddocumentsequence%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): Full trust for the immediate caller. This member cannot be used by
  >   partially trusted code.
- According to
  [What is XPS files and how it is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758497/what-is-xps-files-and-how-it-is-being-used)
  that method works when single threaded (STA). Read more about STA in ASP.NET  http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/18/Creating-STA-COM-compatible-ASPNET-Applications